# FreeBSD zone allocator

Tags: freebsd

I am reading the freeBSD book authored by Marshall McKusick and George Neville-Neil. In the kernel memory management, it mentions the following about zone allocator:

> Each memory type is given its own zone from which all its allocations are made. Memory allocated in one zone cannot be used by any other zone or by the general memory allocator.

My question is:

1) What memory types are being referred here ?

2) What is meant by the different zones in context of zone allocator ?

If someone can also provide some reference that explains this better, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The zone allocator in FreeBSD is [uma(9)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uma&sektion=9).

From the manual page:

> The zone allocator first appeared in FreeBSD 3.0. It was radically
>   changed in FreeBSD 5.0 to function as a [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocator).

A *zone* is similar to a memory arena/region in a memory pool, but as the manual page mentions, with slab allocator-like features. As your quote implies, you cannot `uma_zalloc()` from one zone and then `uma_zfree()` that chunk into a different zone. That'd screw with the internal bookkeeping.

As for *memory types*, I assume it refers to different kernel structures, where different kernel structures would probably have one zone each.